# Terraform AWS Security Group settings to allow all ports between all VMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I'm kinda stumped. I have a custom service (named bacalhau) running on each of three machines in a security group on 54545. I also have SSH running on all machines. Here's what my terraform looks like:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "allow_ssh_and_bacalhau" {
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.bacalhau_vpc.id
  name        = "allow_ssh_and_bacalhau"
  description = "security group that allows ssh and bacalhau and all egress traffic"

}
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "egress_all" {
  type              = "egress"
  from_port         = 0
  to_port           = 0
  protocol          = "-1"
  cidr_blocks       = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.allow_ssh_and_bacalhau.id
}


resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ingress_ssh" {
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 22
  to_port           = 22
  protocol          = "-1"
  cidr_blocks       = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.allow_ssh_and_bacalhau.id
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ingress_bacalhau" {
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 54545
  to_port           = 54545
  protocol          = "-1"
  self              = true
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.allow_ssh_and_bacalhau.id
}
```

SSH works fine - including inter-traffic between machines, but the bacalhau (54545) service doesn't show up.

E.g.

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-219:~$ nmap ec2-18-202-245-138.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-03-19 18:07 UTC
Nmap scan report for ec2-18-202-245-138.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com (10.0.1.237)
Host is up (0.0022s latency).
rDNS record for 10.0.1.237: ip-10-0-1-237.eu-west-1.compute.internal
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.08 seconds
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-219:~$
```

**EDIT** The nmap is running from a VM inside the security group.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a security group, vpc, or ec2 mistake? I *can* access the service from the node itself through localhost loop back.

**EDIT 2** Confirmed this is a security group issue - I turned on accepting inbound from everywhere [0.0.0.0/0] and it worked fine.

Comment: Where is that `nmap` command running? On one of the 3 machines in that security group? Do you have a service actually started and running on each of those servers that is listening on port `54545`? All the security group does is allow that traffic on that port on the network level. If you don't have a service running on the server that is actually listening on that port, then I wouldn't expect that to show up.

Comment: My apologies - the nmap is running from an instance inside the security group. I _do_ have a service running on that port (if I ssh in, set the host to be localhost and the port to be 54545, it works correctly.

Comment: Are you experiencing an actual issue? Like when the instances try to communicate with each other over port `54545` does that fail? Or is your question only about `nmap`? Also, what sort of service do you have running that is listening on port `54545`? Is it possible that service is only bound to `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: What are your actual SGs, not only rules?

Comment: @MarkB yeah, when I connect from the instance back to itself on localhost, it works properly so I think it’s something else. Could be a default firewall on the machine (do default Ubuntu amis ship with one?) or security group/rule.

Comment: @Marcin happy to pass along - is that different than the first line above?

Comment: You didn't really answer any of my requests for clarification. You just said localhost works, which isn't something I asked.

Comment: Sorry, you asked if I was experiences an actual issue, which, by saying localhost works, I was trying to indicate that the service is working, it's just internode communication that's not. 

To add further detail, when I open all nodes to the world, the internode communication works fine - so it's definitely something wrong with the security group settings.

Answer (score 0):

For `ingress_bacalhau` security group rule you have set argument of `self = true`. This will allow traffic only from another instance which also has the `allow_ssh_and_bacalhau` security group attached.

In contrast, for SSH with `ingress_ssh` rule you allow traffic from the whole internet (`cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]`)

You do not specify clearly from which instance was the `nmap` scan executed. If this instance does not have the `allow_ssh_and_bacalhau` security group attached, then the traffic wont be allowed from it.

Comment: Thanks for the response - All the VMs are in the same security group, provisioned at the same time.
The nmap is running from an instance inside the security group.